# Print SQL results on separate lines

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the SQL statement below:

```
create table dbo.test(id int identity, Name varchar(10))
 insert into test values ('ian')
 insert into test values ('andy')
 insert into test values ('vicky')

SELECT TOP 1
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + Name AS [text()]
                FROM dbo.Test 
               ORDER BY id
                 FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 0, '' ) Concatenated
 FROM TEST
```

It returns a single string value: `,ian,andy,vicky` as expected. If I print the result on a webpage it prints: ian,andy,vicky as expected.  Is there any way it can print:

ian
andy
vicky

i.e. on separate lines?

Comment: Once you have the result (which you are concatenated), you can split it at the " " and have 3 seperate values in an array.  Then you can do whatever you want with them.

Comment: @durbnpoisn, I realise you can do it in code e.g. VB.  However, I wandered if there was a way of achieving this at the SQL level.

Comment: I answered this, but WOW this seems like a case where the OP has NO IDEA what is going on in any way.

Comment: @Hogan, that is harsh.  I have six years full development experience with .NET and SQL.  I am maintaining a poor legacy system and this is the best way I can see of adding some basic functionality without major refactoring.

Comment: @w0051977 - sure -- then why not change the `,` to `<BR/>`?

Comment: @Hogan,  Borat Sagdiyev's comment under your answer has nailed it.  I will mark your answer after the time limit expires.

Comment: I can't create an sqlfiddle for this. I get the error `Unknown Error Occurred: a timeout occurred on a exclusive lock with name [cfadmin] after 30 seconds: `

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT TOP 1
       STUFF((SELECT '<BR/>' + Name AS [text()]
                FROM dbo.Test 
               ORDER BY id
                 FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 5, '' ) Concatenated
                 -- could be this if depending on any xxs settings on sql server
                 -- FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 11, '' ) Concatenated


 FROM TEST
```

Comment: Thanks.  That is what I originally thought.  However the output is: &lt;BR/&gt;ian&lt;BR/&gt;andy&lt;BR/&gt;vicky.

Comment: SQL = `&lt;BR/&gt;ian&lt;BR/&gt;andy&lt;BR/&gt;vicky`, HTML = `<BR/>ian<BR/>andy<BR/>vicky`. Tested on chrome.

Comment: @w0051977 - dude, that is supposed to be interpreted by your browser. see my comment.

Comment: ok @w0051977 -- what do you actually want -- I removed the leading `<BR/>` is that what was bothering you?

Comment: @Hogan - SQL = `R/&gt;ian&lt;BR/&gt;andy&lt;BR/&gt;vicky` and HTML = `R/>ian<BR/>andy<BR/>vicky`

Comment: This is what I was after.  I originally tried this answer.  Borat Sagdiyev's comment has helped.  +1.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev - I added in a comment about how to fix that -- on your system `<` is being translated

Comment: @w0051977 - does this help `select (name + '</BR>') AS Html 
from test` ? HTML is not my thing.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev - I'm guessing this is a simplified version of the actual query and making a change like that would actually change a lot of other stuff -- the only way I can explain the question.

Comment: @Hogan - with your current query, the output is `R/>ian<BR/>andy<BR/>vicky` on chrome in windows 7 64 bit. Why is that first `</BR>` getting converted to `<R/>`. Can you please add the fix for that to your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev - do you see the edit I made?  It is in a comment, change the 5 to an 11.

Comment: @Hogan - Sorry, missed that. After changing 5 to 11, SQL = `ian&lt;BR/&gt;andy&lt;BR/&gt;vicky` and HTML = `ian<BR/>andy<BR/>vicky`

Answer (score 1):

You mean This?

`SELECT NAME FROM TEST`

Comment: It will be really weird if he wants this. :)

Comment: My thoughts the same. I was questioning whether to post it or not, then went ahead anyways.