# How to shift the value to the next row in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table input like

```
column1 | column2 
--------+--------
1,2,3   | A,B,C
4,5,6   | D,E,F
```

I need output like this:

```
column1 |column2
--------+-------
  1     | A
  2     | B
  3     | C 
  4     | D
  5     | E
  6     | F
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server split CSV into multiple rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811161/sql-server-split-csv-into-multiple-rows)

Comment: Doing it via server itself will be slow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print SQL results on separate lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22820038/print-sql-results-on-separate-lines)

Comment: Are there always exactly three values in each column corresponding to exactly three values in the second column (1->a, 2->b and so on...)?

Comment: Not exactly three it can more in both the column.

Answer (score 0):

You question is quite unclear, but my magic crystal ball tells me, that you might be looking for something like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,column1 VARCHAR(100),column2 VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('1,2,3','A,B,C')
,('4,5,6','D,E,F');

WITH Casted AS
(
    SELECT ID
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(column1,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' AS XML) AS col1XML
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(column2,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' AS XML) AS col2XML
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT ID,col1XML.value('/x[1]','int') AS Column1,col2XML.value('/x[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Column2
FROM Casted 
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,col1XML.value('/x[2]','int') AS Column1,col2XML.value('/x[2]','nvarchar(max)') AS Column2
FROM Casted 
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,col1XML.value('/x[3]','int') AS Column1,col2XML.value('/x[3]','nvarchar(max)') AS Column2
FROM Casted 
ORDER BY ID,Column1
```

The result

```
ID  c1  c2
1   1   A
1   2   B
1   3   C
2   4   D
2   5   E
2   6   F
```

Comment: Thanks @Shnugo this what I am looking for